# Replacing various types of empty lists with np.nan

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe which contains a list of strings, an empty list, an empty string within a list, and a string of empty brackets (I guess).

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'column 1':[['97010', '97110', '97140'],[],[''],'[]']})
```

How do I remove or replace each of the last three types of empty lists (strings) with np.nan? It doesn't have to be a one-liner. Anything syntactically readable will do just fine.

I tried:

```
list(filter(None, df2['column 1']))
```

which removes the first empty list. But how do I remove the [''] and '[]'?

Comment: Define an empty list, please. My understanding is, a list with no elements is empty. And `[""]` is not an empty list. `print(len([""]))` -> `1`. `[{'[()]'}]` would you consider this as an empty list too??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by screening for all possible empty cases. The code is as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'column 1':[['97010', '97110', '97140'],[],[''],'[]']})
df2["column 1"] = df2["column 1"].astype(str).replace(["[]", "['']"], np.nan)
df2
```

The output is:

```
    column 1
0   ['97010', '97110', '97140']
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
```

---

Explanation:
Basically screen for all possible empty sequences in the replace function's first parameter and the replace them with `nan`s.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to filter these rows out, you can use isin().

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'column 1':[['97010', '97110', '97140'],[],[''],'[]']})

df = df2[~df2['column 1'].astype(str).isin([nan,'[]', "['']"])]

print(df)
```

Output :

```
    column 1
0  [97010, 97110, 97140]
```